# How can I access class instance(object) pointer in "boost::function"?

Tags: c++, boost, pointer-to-member, boost-function

```
CClass inst;
boost::function<bool(int)> func = boost::bind(&CClass::Foo, &inst, _1);
```

In this situation,
I want to access inst's pointer(&inst) or address from "func" like below.

```
CClass* pInstance = func.obj_ptr; (This is just a form that I want)
```

How can I do?

Comment: Where do you want to access `func`'s internals from? Is it from within the same scope in which `func` is defined, or is it from within the scope of the function `func` is passed on to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way, with the use of [`boost::function::target()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost/function_base.html#id334950-bb) template method. But since `boost::bind` return unspecified type, witch do not yet provide a way to access arguments, you will need to write your own binder functor. Here is some example:

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
    void myMethod()
    {
        std::cout << "This is my Method" << std::endl; 
    }
};

struct MyFunctor
{
    MyFunctor(MyClass* o, void (MyClass::*m)()): object(o),method(m){}
    MyClass* object;
    void (MyClass::*method)();

    void  operator() ()
    {
        return (object->*method)();
    }
};
```

So now you can access:

```
MyClass myObject;
boost::function< void() > func= MyFunctor(&myObject, &MyClass::myMethod);
func();

assert( func.target<MyFunctor>()->object == &myObject );
```

Same as with the `boost::any` there is no way to have polymorphic access witch the `target` template method.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot. The whole point of `boost/std::function` is to *erase* the type that was stored within it. To implement what you're talking about would require re-constituting the type. And since C++ is a statically-typed language, that means the code that calls such a function would have to explicitly provide the type being returned. Something like `func.value<TypeName>()`.

Even moreso, what you're talking about wouldn't be possible even if that were available. The only type that `function` knows about is the type it was *given*. Which is the return value from `boost/std::bind`. That type is not widely available without digging into the implementation specifics.

So what you're asking for is not possible. Not without storing it elsewhere yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that such member (argument) should be not public within boost::function class. If I am right, you won't be able to do it. At least without some strange operations.

If you really need something similar and are creator of func objects, the most clean way I can imagine right now is:
`std::pair<boost::function<bool(int)>, CClass *> funcAndObj`, then call `funcAndObj.first()` and get the pointer from `funcAndObj.second`.